# Coalescing multiple columns using multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to coalesce multiple columns using multiple conditional statements. In the example below I want to coalesce with A taking precedence over B followed by C where A is >= 0.1 and < 30, while where A is NA, < 0.1 or > 30 I was to coalesce with B taking precedence over A followed by C.

Below is an example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(1:8)
df$A <- c(102, 0.04, 0.1, NA_real_, 0.01, 0.01, 0.2, NA_real_)
df$B <- c(20.2, 50.1, 10.1, 6.1, 7.1, NA_real_, 8.1, NA_real_)
df$C <- c(NA_real_, 4.1, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 8.1, NA_real_, 10.1)


      A    B    C
1   102 20.2   NA
2  0.04 50.1  4.1
3   0.1 10.1   NA
4    NA  6.1   NA
5  0.01  7.1   NA
6  0.01   NA  8.1
7   0.2  8.1   NA
8    NA   NA 10.1
```

Below is the desired output:

```
      A    B    C new_col
1   102 20.2   NA    20.2
2  0.04 50.1  4.1    50.1
3   0.1 10.1   NA     0.1
4    NA  6.1   NA     6.1
5  0.01  7.1   NA     7.1
6  0.01   NA  8.1     8.1
7   0.2  8.1   NA     0.2
8    NA   NA 10.1    10.1
```

I tried to solve this using mutate and the coalesce functions in the code below but did not get the desired output (in many cases this works OK as long as the value in column A is a value where the value is NA, Nulls are produced in the output).

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(new_col = if_else(A >= 0.1 & A <= 30, 
                           coalesce(A, B, C),
                           coalesce(B, A, C)))

      A    B    C new_col
1   102 20.2   NA    20.2
2  0.04 50.1  4.1    50.1
3   0.1 10.1   NA     0.1
4    NA  6.1   NA    NULL
5  0.01  7.1   NA     7.1
6  0.01   NA  8.1    0.01
7   0.2  8.1   NA     0.2
8    NA   NA 10.1    NULL
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you have added columns `A` , `B` and `C` as list?

Comment: No, I was just trying to generate a data frame as an example, I realise that there might be an easy way to achieve this

Comment: Yes, replace `list` with `c`.

Comment: Why is row 6 `8.1`, shouldn't it be 0.01 since the order is B- > A- > C  and row 2 should be 50.1 since `0.04 < 0.1`

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I have edited the post so that list is now c

Comment: Ronak you are correct, row 6 should be 8.1 and row 2 should be 20.2. I have edited the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is correct but you need to handle `NA`'s since `NA` in `if_else` returns `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(new_col = if_else(A >= 0.1 & A <= 30 & !is.na(A), 
                           coalesce(A, B, C),
                           coalesce(B, A, C)))


#       A    B    C new_col
#1 102.00 20.2   NA   20.20
#2   0.04 50.1  4.1   50.10
#3   0.10 10.1   NA    0.10
#4     NA  6.1   NA    6.10
#5   0.01  7.1   NA    7.10
#6   0.01   NA  8.1    0.01
#7   0.20  8.1   NA    0.20
#8     NA   NA 10.1   10.10
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(102, 0.04, 0.1, NA_real_, 0.01, 0.01, 0.2, NA_real_),
         B =  c(20.2, 50.1, 10.1, 6.1, 7.1, NA_real_, 8.1, NA_real_),
         C = c(NA_real_, 4.1, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 8.1, NA_real_, 10.1))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(new_col = case_when(A >= 0.1 & A <= 30 & !is.na(A) ~ 
                   coalesce(A, B, C), TRUE ~ coalesce(B, A, C)))
```